# SE App doesn't respect the "sync" setting

Tags: feature-request, android-app

If I globally disable synchronization on my Android phone using the "sync" toggle in the power control widget (2nd from the right)

[image: power control widget]

all applications cease updating their status over the network, like fetching emails etc. I'd be very nice if the SE app followed the flag and stopped network communication as well.

From the user point of view, this would mean in particular not to fetch and display **push notifications**.

I know that it's possible to specify a time range to disable them, but following the general settings would be much more flexible and it wouldn't be necessary to handle the SE app separately.

Comment: From what I observed, the sync function only affects apps that has accounts settings (Settings - Accounts). Meanwhile, SE app doesn't use that function (no account created). On the other hand, based on [this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20098676/2821954), it's possible to check for the sync status.

Comment: Andrew T. is correct. Sync status is for syncing of "Accounts". We _can_ check the state in the application, but what would you expect for it to do? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi I'm not that familiar with the Android internals, but it seems the "sync" toggle is global - it affects all the accounts on my phone.

Comment: @PetrPudlák yes it effects the syncing of the accounts, that is, your Contacts being synced with Google, your Calendars being kept up to date, it doesn't have any effect on specific applications.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi That I understand, but the question is if the setting is account-specific or not. If it's not, it'd make sense for an app to check the setting and act accordingly. If different accounts on the same phone can have different settings, then probably not.

Comment: It's global for all of your sync accounts. These are the accounts that are Mail, Calendar, Contacts, and sometimes other apps that do data syncing (Spotify, for example)

Comment: Rephrasing Kasra's question: what do you expect the app to do if the sync option is on/off? AFAIK, the app doesn't sync anything *in the background*, you have to open the app to refresh the content, with network connected. Unless, you were talking about the widgets (HNQ and Rep widgets). If that's the case, then yes, I believe it's still refreshing the data even with global sync off, since it's actually not connected to global sync. So, could you explain the detail of your request?

Comment: Hmm... I think I understand a bit more. Since you're also mentioning the "Quiet Hours" feature, I think you're talking about the **push notification**?

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes, sorry for not describing it more clearly. I'll update the question.